# Overriding global anchor hover styles in footer

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

I have used the global element selector `a:hover{}` for hovering over most elements in the web page. But for all the elements in the footer, I would like to override the hovering effect.

So my question is how can I override the element selector `a:hover{}` when it is used elsewhere since I don't want all the `a` elements to hover

HTML

```
<body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header_logo">
                <img id ="logo" src="civic-logo.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="header_title">
                <div id="titles">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT CIVIC</a><li>
                            <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>  
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">CEMENT</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">STEEL</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">BRICKS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">SAND</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a> </li>
                        </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="content">
                    <img src="images/clt3.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <div class="footer_upperspace">

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">CIVIC HOME</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">INQUIRY</a></li>
                            </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>


                </body>
```

CSS

```
    /*Main Header Container */
    .header{
      color:#FFFFFF;    /*White Color*/
      height:60px;
      width:100%;
      margin:auto;
    }
    /*Inner Logo Container on the left*/
    .header_logo{
      width:40%;
      height:100%;
      float:left;
    }
    #logo{
      height:100%;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width:50%;
    }
    /*Inner Title Container on the right*/
    .header_title{
      width:60%;
      float:left;
    }
    #titles{
      position:absolute;
      top:20px;
      font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif,Georgia;
      font-size:97%;
      color:#B8B8B8;
    }
    ul{
      list-style-type:none;
    }
    li{
      display:inline-block;
    }

    a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color:inherit;
      padding: 21px 10px;
    }

    ul a:hover{
      background-color:#666699;  /*Purple Color */

    }

    ul li ul{
      display:none; /*Hiding The Child Elements*/
    }
    li ul li{
        padding: 21px 10px;
        background-color:#666699 ;
        }


    ul li:hover ul{   /*For all the ul elements whose parent is being hovered over*/
      display: block;
      position: absolute;

      width: 100%;
      top: 40px;
      left: 0;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    ul li ul li:hover{
        background-color:#C0C0C0;   
        }

      *{border:0;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        }
    /*Main Content Section*/
    .content{
        height:525px;
        margin:auto;
        background-color:#C0C0C0;
        }
        img{
            width:1280px;
            height:515px;
            }
/*Footer*/

        .footer {
        margin:auto;
        background-color:#707070;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .footer_upperspace  {
        background-color:#C0C0C0;
        height:40%;
    }
```

I have attached the JSFiddle to give you an insight of what I am doing

https://jsfiddle.net/rajivsr2309/b2o3Lzny/

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @Shomz I have modified it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a stricter selector (with higher [specificity](https://specificity.keegan.st/)) to override the less strict one. For example:

```css
a:hover {color: red}
a.cancel:hover {color: green}
```

```html
<a href="">Some link</a>
<a href="">Some link</a>
<a href="">Some link</a>
<a href="">Some link</a>
<a href="" class="cancel">Some different link</a>
<a href="">Some link</a>
```

In your case, the selector is: `.footer a:hover`: https://jsfiddle.net/b2o3Lzny/2/

---

Again, since you're trying to undo a general rule, perhaps your approach is wrong and you could consider making a specific class just for those anchors you **want** to style, not all of the anchors, and then undo many of them.

Comment: Can you share some light on creating a specific class for styling certain anchors? You mean to say that as a general rule, to have anchors not hovering and that  a specific class should only be applied to the anchors which I want to hover. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly that! Basically I'm suggesting whitelisting vs. blacklisting here. In your case, you can even put an ID to the `ul` and use the selector `#myUL a:hover`, for example. Don't forget, though, all browsers apply some styling to all anchor hovers (text underline), so those ones need to be overriden in case you don't want them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.footer a:hover { background-color: yellow; }
```

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/b2o3Lzny/1/)

With `.footer` preceding `a:hover`, this is now a [*descendant combinator selector*](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators) which matches only hovered anchor elements that exist within elements with class `footer`.